# Date range offset

Tags: javascript, date, days

I want to generate a array's date offset

for e.g:

input :

```
dayjs()
```

Output :

```
["16/08/2022","23/08/2022","30/08/2022","6/09/2022"]
```

as you can see dates are offset (weeks) , I have no idea how to implement  this

Any hints please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually, take `Date.now()` and add it:

weekNumber * 7 (days) * 24 (hours) * 60 (minutes) * 60 (seconds) * 1000 (milliseconds)

```js
function getWeeksFromNow(numWeeks) {
  let arr = []
  
  for (let i = 0; i < numWeeks; i++) {
    let x = new Date(Date.now() + i * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    arr.push(x.toISOString())
  }
  
  return arr
}



console.log( getWeeksFromNow(4) )
```